# Gatling - print the POST request URI

Tags: post, gatling

I would like to print the URI and want to verify the POST URI request is formed correctly, Can you please advise how to verify the POST URI request if URI is substituted/formed correctly?

```
object BidSubmission extends HttpUtil {

  val orders_feeder = csv("data/Round-1.csv").circular

  def orderSubmission: ChainBuilder =
    pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
      .repeat(1) {
        feed(orders_feeder)
          .exec(postToUri(s"${Constants.orderSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid", "")
            .queryParam("employeeId", "#{empNo}")
            .body(StringBody(session => {
              println(session)
              println(session.attributes("empNo"))
              val empNo = session.attributes("empNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              val orderNo = session.attributes("orderNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              println(s"\n\n\n $orderNo \n\n\n")
              var slotNos = orderNo.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(" +")
              println(s"\n\n\n ${generatePayload(empNo, slotNos)} \n\n\n")
              generatePayload(empNo, slotNos)
              " "
            }))
          )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tune the logback configuration file. Please have a look at the documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/configuration/#logbackxml

Comment: Than you , will take a look at it, ok, i printed  println(s"${Constants.orderSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid") meanwhile and it did not replace AuctionId in the URI looks like, and it displayed ------> Output:   https://order.com/golden/base-auction/system-override/auctions/#{AuctionId}/base-auctions/proxy-bid 

Can you please advise how to replace Auctionid with the session variable here?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing exactly. I suspect you're confusing Gatling Expression Language and Scala String interpolation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html. If you're struggling with Scala, you should maybe use Java instead.

Comment: I am trying to replace AuctionId session variable to the POST Request URI .exec(postToUri(s"${Constants.orderSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid", "") and i couldnt replace AuctionId session variable to form the URI, I couldnt find what i am doing wrong here,